# How do I export a regex as a const in es6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a regex which is repeatedly used in a number of classes. It's a violation of DRY and a potential pain if it needs to be changed in the future. Therefore I decided to move it to a common js and export it. Below is the code:

```
const CommonValues = {
  TEXT_FILTER_REGEX: /^[,.?!:"—]$/
};
export CommonValues;
```

After importing CommonValues, I use it like this:

`let result = CommonValues.TEXT_FILTER_REGEX.test('foo,bar'));`

But no matter what I try, I keep getting this error in the console:

Uncaught Error: Module parse failed: 'const' can not be used as shorthand property (5:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

I also tried exporting an integer and string the same way, they both worked without any trouble. This makes me wonder if regex is somehow treated differently when it comes to exporting?

This appears to have fixed itself miraculously. I'm totally baffled. I guess would be a temporary babel glitch.

Thanks for any advise.

Comment: Like what Jonas said looks like your front-end build tool doesn't know what to do with ES6 code

Comment: Your syntax is not correct and this may be why your bundler trips. Either use `export {CommonValues}` or `export default CommonValues`, depending on what you want.

Comment: However, I would suggest to simply export the value as `export const TEXT_FILTER_REGEX =  /^[,.?!:"—]$/;`.

Comment: @Jonas, I'm using babel and webpack.

Comment: @FelixKling I tried. Nope, didn't work.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "didn't work"?

Comment: @FelixKling Actually, overnight this appeared to have fixed itself mysteriously. No more console errors. I'm completely mystified.

Comment: @binjiezhao can u try my answer?

Answer (score 2):

I go it working by doing the below.
I'm not sure what your `RegExp` '`/^[,.?!:"—]$/`' does, but I tried with a `digit` `RegEx =^[0-9]$` and got the expected result;

The error I got is about `string` type not having a test() defined on its prototype in TypeScript. Only RegExp has.

```
export const Constants = {
  TEXT_FILTER_REGEX:  new RegExp('^[,.?!:"—]$')
}
```

A working plunker is  [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/r8SxJykPtZH1zaqAZsI6)

Test can be done the exact same way. You need to trim the `/`s and make it a `RegExp` object using a

```
new RegExp('UrRegexHere')
```